# How to create an excel formula with IF along with AND and multiple OR conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to create an IF statement with AND and multiple OR conditions from two sheets. Basically, first thing that Excel should do is check Column A if the cell value is blank or not. Then once it has this determined, it should check Columns B, C, D if any of them has values or not. If any one of these 3 columns has value, set to True. And if all 3 columns is blank, set to False.

I have tried these formulas;

```
=IF(AND(Raw!AK6<>"",OR(Raw!AM6<>"",Raw!AN6<>"",Raw!AO6<>"")),"",Raw!D6)
```

and also;

```
=IF(AND(Raw!AK3<>"",OR(Raw!AM3<>"",OR(Raw!AN3<>"",OR(Raw!AO3<>"")))),"",Raw!D3)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "...first check Column A if the cell value is blank or not. Then once it has this determined...": so how does that determination impact the subsequent logic?

Comment: Hi Marc - if Column A is blank, the other conditions shouldn't apply anymore. But if it has value, it should check the conditions on the other 3 columns. 
hope this clarifies. Thanks!

Comment: Still not clear.  If columns A thru D are all blank, what should be returned?  False?  Please state your logic very specifically.  I assume you already have an answer based on what's below, but those guys are kindly assuming what you haven't been explicit about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula ISBLANK() and invert the concepts:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Raw!AK6),AND(ISBLANK(Raw!AM6),ISBLANK(Raw!AN6),ISBLANK(Raw!AO6))),Raw!D6,"")
```

See results (Column D = "Yes"):

[image]

Comment: Hi Kaiser - thanks for your answer.. It seems the formula doesn't meet the condition for "if any of columns AM, AN, AO is blank" set to true.

Comment: Check it again, see the screenshot with the results. I think the formula provides what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(AND(Raw!AK3<>"",COUNTIFS(AM3:AO3,"<>")>0),Raw!D3,"")
```

But basically your first formula would work, you just have the TRUE/FALSE reversed:

```
=IF(AND(Raw!AK6<>"",OR(Raw!AM6<>"",Raw!AN6<>"",Raw!AO6<>"")),Raw!D6,"")
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution. I was working in something different but this is better

Comment: Hi Scott - I tried this and it works. However, I believe I didn't encompass the condition that if Columns AM:AO all has values, set it to False. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @erlomboy you stated `If any one of these 3 columns has value, set to True` which this does.

Comment: How can we add another condition of =3 aside from >0 on your formula so that it would also check for all 3 columns has values?

Comment: if that is the case that you want all three to have a value then yes change the `>0` to `=3`